# python - IOError: [Errno 2] - Can permissions cause an IOError Errno 2 when using open()

Tags: python, linux, cron

I have a python script which creates a tar file, moves files into the tar file, and then deletes them.

I am able to run the script manually without a problem.  But when it is run from cron, it fails with:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'directory/filename_2014-08-08.tar.gz'
```

Is it possible that a file permissions issue can raise Errno 2 in this case?

Here is the relevant code:

```
fname = directory + "_" + str(strftime("%Y-%m-%d_", localtime()))+".tar.gz"
tar = tarfile.open(archived_model_dir + fname.replace("/",""), "w:gz") # this line raises error
for input_file in os.listdir(directory):
    if os.path.isfile(directory + input_file):
        if not input_file.endswith('.pyc'):  
            tar.add(directory + input_file) # archive all but .pyc
        os.remove(directory + input_file)
    elif os.path.exists(directory + input_file): # delete subfolders 
        shutil.rmtree(directory + input_file)
```

The tar file is created with tarfile.open().  Again it works successfully if ran by my user but fails with the above error when run from cron.  I'm wondering if the user that runs cron doesn't have proper permissions to create the tar file, and could that possibly raise Errno 2?

I will do a few tests with user permissions to see if this is the case, but maybe some SO user can provide a faster answer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the current working directory. That could be the reason of the error.

```
import os
print(os.getcwd())
```

If that's the problem, make all paths absolute:

```
fname = os.path.join('/path/to/directory/', directory + "_" + .... + ".tar.gz")
```

or change the directory before run the script. (in the Python script or in crontab entry)

```
import os
os.chdir('/path/to/directory')
```

Comment: That definitely seems like a more likely explanation.  Will take a look

Comment: That was it.  Added cd /script/dir/ to the crontab and it works.